# android: how to restart an ativity which was previously full

Tags: android, singleton, lifecycle, android-activity

i've got 2 activities. one activity questions an external db through a web service and shows the results on another activity. 
what i want is that when i press the back hardware key i should get back to the first activity and when i do another request the 2nd activitystart all over again.
here's the code of the onBackPressed() method im using but it doesnt work! i go back to the first activity which is correct but when i do another request  2 second activity starts from where i left it the first time. for example, i have page numbers at the bottom of the 2nd activity and if i press the back hardware button from page number 3 and do another request my second activity restarts from page 3 with all its data. what am i doeing wrong. Am i doing something wrong with the android lifecycle or (as im using a singleton class to do the requests to the webservice/db) am i making a mistake using the singleton? i think my mistake is more on the first point on the lifecycle.
any help would be appreciated. thanks!

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();       
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, pluto.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with your singleton, it has nothing to do with the fact that the state of the next activity is not resetted when brought to the back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default backpress in android removes the current activity from the stack and brings onTop the previous activity.(Thats what you are looking for).

I couldn't understand the reason why you are overriding it at the first place and also the creating a new instance of the activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, pluto.class);     
startActivity(intent)
```

Try commenting this method alltogether to see if that works.

Edit 1

Tasks and Back Stack [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Comment: i started a new instance of activity because i wanted to clear the state of my activity for reuse, but apparently its not working. is there anyother way?

Comment: Is pluto.class your first activity?

Comment: yes it is. ahhhhhh i dont restart the 2 activity. but how do i restrt both of them together?

Comment: @HassanSamii you actually are creating a new instance of the activity on top of the existing stack rather then retstarting the existing activity(read activity1) from stack. I would recommend you to go through the Tasks and Back Stack link i added in the answer which will make things clear for you. The activity statck after excution of your onBackPressed() would look like Activity1 -> Activity2 -> Activity 1 (instead of just Activity1). Try commenting the above method and see if that works.

Comment: yes, the link is realy very useful, but how exacly (code) do i clear my back stack of all activities and get back to activity1 so that i can start all over again? is it better to do by androidmanifest or by flags? plese show me.thanks

Comment: You dont need to oveeride onBackPressed() for that. Just comment this method. The default behaviour in android is if you press back in an activity it is removed from stack(so let say you press back on activity2, it will be removed from the stack and what you will have is just activity1 in stack.)

Comment: i tried puuting intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); in the onBackPressedMethod before startActivity(..) but nothing has changed. why?

Comment: In that case the issue isnt with this portion of code.because FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP will restart Activity1 and remove Activity2 from stack and now if you try to move to Activity2 the life cycle methods should get invoked again.

Comment: it has to be because it doesnt clear my activity. it shoud though!

Comment: can u edit and put all the code above so that i can help you better.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9737/discussion-between-deva-and-hassan-samii)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to reset activity number two when you press back, you should do this manually in the onBackPressed method.
Also using singelton in Android can be a bit messy, since you're not in complete control over when activities are destroyed. Are you sure you need to use it? Android do the state saving automatically.
And as Devastating said, you don't need to manually start activity one when back is pressed.

Comment: i have to use singleton because other wise im not allowed to call and use static methods and variables from different classes, which i need, to dynamically change my URL

Answer (score 0):

Actually u r finishing the current activity before invoking the another in onBackPressed() method. So if you want to get ur work done just remove the finish(); command from the method and call it in onPause() of that activity.

Comment: tried, but it doesnt work. i need to destroy the instance and then create a new one

Comment: then try to call onCreate() method with fresh savedInstanceState in first activity. This will reCreate ur activity instance.

Comment: just call onCreate() with fresh savedInstanceState as parameter in onResume() of activity which u want to restart.